# Java String comparison best practice

Tags: java

why this code

```
"name".equals(person.getName());
```

is better than

```
person.getName().equals("name");
```

Comment: `"name"` will never be null

Comment: `person.getName()` might return `null` however whether ignoring a `null` value is better than throwing an exception is debatable.

Comment: #2 has a problems: person and `getName` are liable to return null. At a minimum, you need to include a null check for both person and getName() (unless you have some other mechanism that guarantees the latter will never be null

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I prefer the *Yoda Expression* `"name".equals(person.getName());` since it means you don't need to check if `person.getName()` is `null`. That saves a bit of typing and is arguably clearer once you get used to it.

Although in your case, you'll still need to check if `person` is not `null`.

Answer (score 1):

Because the constant `"name"` can never be `null`.

```
"name".equals(null)
```

is valid and will return false, whereas

```
String personName = null;
personName.equals("name");
```

will throw a `NullPointerException`

Answer (score 1):

```
"name".equals(person.getName());
```

This code will avoid Null pointer exception.

Comment: still need to check if "person" is null because null.getName() will NPE